# How to use oData interface options with Avro similar to JSON format for exposing the data

Tags: odata, avro, hana, hana-xs

I have created an XSOdata service in SAP HANA and the external system needs in AVRO format rather than JSON format.

JSON format looks like below with a link and its developments on a HANA Calculation view:

```
https://HANA_SERVER/package_name/XSODATA_NAME.xsodata/name_event?$format=json

XSODATA_NAME.xsodata file contains:

service {
"package_name::CA_CALC_VIEW" as "name_event"
keys generate local "ID"                            
aggregates always;
}

.xsapp

{}

.xsaccess

{"exposed":true}
```

Could you please suggest on how to expose a XSOData as AVRO format. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Odata services (and also the service generators) don’t support the AVRO format. 
If you want to expose data via this format, a custom OData service implementation is required, that is, you would have to either develop it yourself or find a 3rd party implementation that you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and feedback @Lars Br. Could you please suggest if there are any standard SAP help documentation available for "custom OData service implementation" in HANA for exposing the data as AVRO from XSOdata. I searched initially the https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM before posting here, could not get the relative one. Again, Thanks for the feedback. It really helps. I am one of the fan of 'There you go, now you know.'

Comment: Glad you like my blog posts. Unfortunately I am not aware of any documentation that would show how to do that kind of development. I’d probably look into how to build something like that in node or Java and connect that to your HANA OData services.